# <number>dd not doing anything on an ubuntu machine

Tags: normal-mode, linux-ubuntu

I use `999dd` as a goto command before pasting/overwriting the entire contents from the clipboard. For some reason this is not working (at all) on a specific ubuntu machine.

Why would this not work be working? Is there a `vim` setting required (or that should be removed) to get this going?

Note: I do realize that `:1,$d` (go to command mode then do `1,$d`) will also work.  I'm just wondering about this difference in behavior.

*Update*  I am seeing some extraneous text intermittently:

> debug2: channel 0: window 994746 sent adjust 53830

That text is actually ending up dumped into the editor buffer. What is that all about?

OK i see this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987330/debug2-channel-x-window-number-sent-adjust-number-2

> This message is the result of connecting to a machine using ssh with the -vv flag turned on. In my case I'd used -vv to diagnose why a client machine was rejecting my connection and had forgotten to close and reopen the session without debug flags after diagnosing the problem.

I am using an alias for connecting via ssh: must have that in there. I will remove it and see if it also fixes the original issue.

Comment: Start vim with `--clean` and try it. That'll give you default config and disable plugins.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but `:%d` is easier to type (at least for me)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble duly noted: I'll have to unlearn the muscle memory and go for that one.